# How to fix the repetition of a table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to display a json as a table. Once i display the table repeats by itself.

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered d-sm-table-row" id="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:10%">IRB#</th>
                        <th>Reg Dt</th>
                        <th>Tx_Start_Dt</th>
                        <th>Tx_End_Dt</th>
                        <th>Off_Study Dt</th>
                        <th style="width:100%">IRB_Title</th>
                        @*<th>Arm_Descr</th>*@
                    </tr>

                </table>


            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://tsrv/Get-Irb-Protos/by-mrn?format=json",
                headers: { "Authorization": "042a9ff198c046eaf21|API Testing Script" },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "id": "35528329" })

            }).done(function (data) {
                /*$('#monitor_data').append(JSON.stringify(data))*/
                //console.log(data);

                $.each(data,
                    function () {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {

                            var tr = $('<tr/>');
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][0] + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][1] + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][2] + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][3] + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][4] + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][5] + "</td>");
                            //tr.append("<td>" + data.rows[i][6] + "</td>");
                            $('table').append(tr);
                        }



                    });

            });
        </script>
```

Expected result :
There will be no repetition of tables row. I am assuming that i have done something wrong in the java-script portion.
Please check the screen shot for further references.
[image]

Comment: What does data look like coming in

Comment: just remove $.each(data,
                    function () { and corresponding closing paranthesis. you're looping twice. for loop is enough

Comment: You have a for loop in an each.  Double looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are looping through data multiple times. Remove the "$.each" loop and run it with just the "for" loop. That should give you one loop of the data. I can help more if you post the response you are receiving from your request.